# How do I change both the image and text of an iOS button?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, button, text

I have a Round Rect Button that is correctly swapping out images.  I want to also change the text within them, but that text does not show up.  Most questions on StackOverflow seem to deal with one but not the other, and the ones that seem most related end up being for a BarItem of some sort.

From within the IBAction for the button's touch, I have the following.

```
 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swappingCorrectly.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [sender setTitle:(@"Aww, this doesn't show up!") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As mentioned, the image is switched just fine -- but that label isn't showing up.  I use the same text-swapping line in another button that isn't swapping images and it works fine.

It just doesn't show up after the first tap.  Anyone know what I can do to make that text show up?

Comment: Are you also setting the attributedTitle somewhere?

Comment: Doing [sender setAttributedTitle:(@"What!")]; caused a 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIAccessibilityBundle setAttributedTitle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance' exception, I'm afraid.

Comment: It's `[UIButton setAttributedTitle:forState:]`, same signature as `setTitle`. Only asking because the attributedTitle will be preferred over the title.

Comment: ^^ FYI Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitle:(@"Aww") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

[image]

[image]

I did notice that the label is to the far right as opposed to dead center.  Is it possible the label is rendering in the wrong spot?  Commenting out the setTitle yields the same results with button title being offset by the image.

How to turn a UIImageView into a button.  Note: this is very dirty and should be wrapped into a class.  I left in but commented out the code to just do something on tap.  Whats not shown is the UIImageView that was thrown on a xib file and set to userenabled = true.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
    [[self fakeButton] addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 25)];
    label.text = @"unpressed";
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [[self fakeButton] addSubview:label];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
//    UIGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
//    UIImageView* temp = (UIImageView*)gesture.view;
//    for (UILabel *label in temp.subviews) {
//        label.text = @"pressed";
//    }
//    temp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.jpeg"];
//    
//    //if you want it to reset after a Delay
//    [self performSelector:@selector(buttonUnpressed:) withObject:temp afterDelay:.2];

}

-(void)buttonUnpressed:(UIImageView*)view
{

//    for (UILabel *label in view.subviews) {
//        label.text = @"unpressed";
//    }
//    view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"origButton.jpeg"];
//    [self performSelector:@selector(buttonUnpressed:) withObject:view afterDelay:.2];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([[self fakeButton] frame], point))
    {
            //Do touch down state
        NSLog(@"touchStarted");
        [[self fakeButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.jpeg"]];
        for (UILabel *label in [[self fakeButton] subviews]) {
            label.text = @"pressed";
        }
    }

}
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touch ended");
    //remove touch down state
    [[self fakeButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"origButton.jpeg"]];
    for (UILabel *label in [[self fakeButton] subviews]) {
        label.text = @"unpressed";
    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Interesting.  My button takes up the whole area, so its absence would make sense if there's an offset taking it off the screen.  Will experiment, thanks!  Also, consider that I have an image both before AND after swapping.

Comment: A couple things I would try is setting the edge offsets [sender setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0)]; or adding a new label and passing the touches through. I personally hate customizing them and usually just use a UIImageView and add gestures and states to it so I have a bit more control.

Comment: I was actually using a UIImageView before with a not-swapping button that had the different image.  When pressed and making it hidden, though, it would no longer be pressed -- it was as if the image took precedence after the button was hidden.  If you have a blog post on how you used a UIImageView, feel free to link it though I'm committed to my missing text for now!

Comment: See the class appended to my answer.

Comment: I shall trust you since I won't be revisiting this for some time to verify it.  Thanks again!